# Swing Popup menus are not completely painted

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jpopupmenu

I have this in several areas of an app I'm working on and I can see no way to replicate it outside of this app. I can't create a sscce since I can't manage to replicate this at all - This leads me to believe that it must be something caused by the parent frame / app, but I have no idea where to look.

What I see is that part of the left hand side of popup menus are not painted. I see this behaviour with JCombobox popups as well as JPopupMenu's. I've attached a couple of images to show what I mean. most of these did work properly previously and without any changes to the code where the popupmenu's are created or displayed, this problem has spread to a lot of other places now.

I'm not mixing heavyweight and lightweight components, as we only use Swing components and the two examples I show below are in completely different parts of the app. The first one is in a fairly simple panel with very little functionality, but the second example (JPoopupMenu) is in a very complex legacy panel.

On both of these and other place where I see it, I'm not altering the parent's clipping region at all and in all case, these popups are constructed and displayed on the EDT.

I know this question is rather vague, but that is because of the nature of the problem. I'll provide any requested info.

[image: JComboBox popup issue]
This specific case happens to be a custom combobox model, but we've seen it when using the DefaultComboBoxModel as well:

```
public class GroupListModel extends AbstractListModel
    implements ComboBoxModel{

private List<groupObject> groups;
private groupObject selectedItem = null;

public GroupListModel() {
    this(new ArrayList<groupObject>());
}

public GroupListModel(List<groupObject> groups) {
    this.groups = groups;
}

@Override
public int getSize() {
    return groups.size();
}

@Override
public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    if(index>=groups.size()){
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    return groups.get(index);
}

public void setGroups(List<groupObject> groups){
    this.groups = groups;
    fireContentsChanged(this, 0, groups.size());
}

public void addElement(groupObject group){
    groups.add(group);
    fireIntervalAdded(this, groups.size()-1, groups.size()-1);
}

public void addElement(groupObject group, int index){
    groups.add(index, group);
    fireIntervalAdded(this, index, index+1);
}

@Override
public void setSelectedItem(Object anItem) {
    if(anItem instanceof groupObject){
        selectedItem = (groupObject) anItem;
    }else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    fireContentsChanged(this, 0, groups.size());
}

@Override
public Object getSelectedItem() {
    return selectedItem;
}
```

This is a JPopupMenu that gets displayed when you right click using the following code:
[image: JPopupMenu paint problem]

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                            if( e.getButton()==e.BUTTON3 ){
                                lastClickedID = tmp.getUniqueID();
                                lastClickedGui = (bigEventGui) gui;
                                itmComplete.setText(
                                        completed ?
                                            ctOne.getLang("uncomplete") :
                                            ctOne.getLang("complete") );
                                itmComplete.setIcon( (completed ?
                                    iconFramework.getIcon(
                                        iconFramework.UNCOMPLETE_ITEM,
                                        24, false) :
                                    iconFramework.getIcon(
                                        iconFramework.COMPLETE_ITEM,
                                        24, false) ));
                                popRCEvent.show(gui, e.getX(), e.getY() );
                            }
```

Comment: Are you by chance mixing heavy weight (AWT) and light weight (Swing) components in the same application?

Comment: Or altering the parent's clipping region inappropriately? An [sscce](http://sscce.org) would help clarify things.

Comment: I'm not mixing heavyweight and lightweight components, as we only use Swing components. The two examples are in completely different parts of the app and I'm not altering the parent's clipping region at all. Something I forgot to mention is that these popups are created and called on the EDT. I can't create a sscce since I can't manage to replicate this at all. It must be something caused by the parent frame / app, but I have no idea where to look.

Comment: Can the popup be clicked in the hidden part (Is the part not painting or not there at all)? And do you know if the popup is heavyweight when that happens?

Comment: No, It seems I can't click on the missing part, but clicking on the visible part works exactly as expected. I don't see any code to setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled() or anything else that could possibly make it heavyweight. --- Actually, I found a call to JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false); in the main class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking out JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false); fixed it... Can somebody please try and explain why?

Comment: This line activated heavyweight popups and mixing lightweight and heavyweight components can result in some problems. (Mostly z-order related stuff) See http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/ for an overview of things one has to expect.

Comment: Updated link for Daniel Rikowski's comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html